# Dangerous file types to avoid in file-sharing website

Tags: php, upload

I am making a small file-sharing website where users can upload content. Recently somebody uploaded a PHP script that was presumably intended to harm the site. It got me thinking: what file types should I block users from uploading? I have already blocked `.exe` files. What other file types could cause harm to either my website or its users?

[This script can be viewed here.](http://pastebin.com/BehD3VvU)

Comment: Harmful to your server is much different than harmful to your users. Do you only care about your server or do you want to avoid people uploading files, which after downloaded by users, will harm them machines?

Comment: Try uploading the file to http://pastebin.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't store the files where they're directly accessible - only provide access via a script YOU control. Don't store the files using their user-supplied filename - use a filename YOU generate (best option is to store file details in a database, including the original filename, and store the actual file using that db record's primary key field.

With those two, people can upload antyhing they want, and there'll be zero chance of the file being executed/interpreted on your server, because it's never in a position where it CAN be executed/interpreted.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem with serving the files with their original filename. I really like the suggestion of serving all content through a script though, this would definitely avoid all problems.

Comment: Ok. Someone uploads `nastyscript.php` and your site places it into a publicly accessible area on the site. They simply hit "http://yourserver.com/uploads/nastyscript.php" in their browser and now the server happily executes that PHP script that THEY upload - allowing arbitrary (and probably malicious code) to run. If you store the file outside of the site's document root so it can't be reached by a direct url, and store it with some randomish filename, there's no way hitting a url in the browser could ever cause the server to run that file.

Comment: You can quite easily serve up the file so it APPEARS to have the original filename using a `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=nastyscript.php`, but on your server, it'll just file `12345`.

Comment: I understand, the filename problem is _if_ your server serves files from the uploaded directory. I was assuming, with a script serving the files, the uploaded files would not be requestable on their own; probably stored off the website's directory structure all together. Thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the script is cut off while it's still defining functions, so I can't make out what it's doing.

However, if you're doing things correctly you should have an `.htaccess` file in your "uploaded files" directory with:

```
Header set Content-Disposition "attachment"
```

This will ensure that accessing any file in that directory will result in a download, and that script will not be run.

(Actually even better is to have the files outside the webroot, and have a "downloader" php script `echo`ing the file contents)

Answer (score 1):

That script could euphemistically be described as a remote administration script.

You should always use a whitelist, not a blacklist. Instead of "enumerating badness", make a list of allowed file types and reject everything else.

Also, all files uploaded should be put in a directory which does not run the PHP handler, or any other script handlers at all (check for instance what other content management systems written in PHP do in the `.htaccess` for their upload directories).

It is also a good idea to put the uploaded files in a separate subdomain which does not have any access to the cookies of the main domain, to avoid attacks which attempt to run JavaScript code on the same origin as the main site (a whitelist of content types is not enough for this, since some browsers are known to guess the content type and treat non-HTML files as HTML).